# JQ, each and input

Tags: jquery

I want to get the array all checked values of input's. But it's not worked...

http://jsfiddle.net/6pjAt/

```
    $('#spoiler_gloss :checked').each(function() {
        spoiler_gloss.push($(this).val());
    });
```

Can anyone say, what i do wrong?

Comment: Please add your relevant HTML to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your elements in the fiddle do not support the "checked" property (see MDN article on the `<input>` element, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

To make it work I used a class instead of the "checked" attr. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6pjAt/1/